# UICollectionView covers full screen on iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a weird issue that I have never met with before. I have a `UICollectionView` over a `UIViewController`. The `UICollectionView` covers the 2/3 of the screen and aligned on bottom. I have a search control above the collection view. Although it runs perfectly on `iOS 12`, UICollectionView covers the whole screen and search control is not visible anymore in `iOS 11`.

I don't have a navigation bar in my view and I am wondering what causes that.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init] ;

    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical ;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0 ;
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0 ;

    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout ;

    self.collectionView.delegate = self ;
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self ;
    self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES ;
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;

    //Number of rows in collectionview
    - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return 11;
    }

    //Bottom space for collection view
    - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        return CGSizeMake(0, 50) ;
    }

}
```

Edit: Contraints image [image: Contraints]

Comment: How you adding searchbar ?

Comment: Both searchbar and collectionview are added in storyboard with their constraints. @PrashantTukadiya

Comment: Constraints looks fine nothing that hides searchbar. You may  debug view hierarchy so see where is your searchbar and button search details is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your constraints

```
Search Bar.top = Safe Area.top
```

Hope this will help.